# Push a viewcontroller if it is not present in the navigation stack

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I want to check whether a viewcontroller is present in a navigation stack or not. If it is present, I need to pop it otherwise I need to push it to the navigation stack. I have tried the following code. If it is not present, control is transfering to the else block but I'm unable to navigate to the screen. Please help me

```
 for aViewController in viewControllers! {

    if aViewController is TabProfileViewController {

      self.navigationController?.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)

     }

    else {

        let lvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(lvc!, animated: true)
      }
}
```

Comment: check your aviewcontroller using if (aviewcontroller.isKind(of: TabProfileViewController.self))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're checking it in every loop, so if one time the first condition is true maybe it can become false in next iteration, so it will pop and push. try following code:

```
if let viewController = viewControllers?.first(where: { $0 is TabProfileViewController }) {
    navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
} else {
    let lvc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController
    navigationController?.pushViewController(lvc!, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code is work for you.

```
    if navigationController != nil && !(navigationController?.topViewController is YOURCONTROLLER) {
        for aViewController in (navigationController?.viewControllers)! 
          {
            if aViewController is YOURCONTROLLER {
            //Your controller found
            }else{
               //push using navigation
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Another way to do that:

```
 if arrViewController != nil && !(arrViewController?.topViewController is TabProfileViewController) {
        for aViewController in (arrViewController?.viewControllers)! {
            if aViewController is Dashboard {
                _ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)
                break
            }
        }
    }else{
         let lvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(lvc!, animated: true)
    }
```